# MUI change bar color on Focus of <Input> component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to find which class i need to override to modify the bar color of the  component:
Here's my code:

```
            <Input
              id="email"
              type="email"
              placeholder="Enter your email"
              className='mr-10'
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
```

The result is this:

[image]

What i want to do is edit the color of the bottom bar.

[image]

Does anyone know which class should i add to my sx{{}} prop to edit the color on focus?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `<TextField />` for this. The `variant` prop will give you the design that you want.

```
<TextField
  variant="standard"
  sx={{
    "& .MuiInput-underline:after": {
      borderBottomColor: "green",
    },
  }}
/>
```

Note that there are other ways too, with `styled` or with `theme`, this is the fastest way to do it but may be not so scalable, so refer to the docs for more styling solutions.

Ref:
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/
https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/#global-css
https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/#global-style-overrides